# Stop a shell script by pressing a button

Tags: bash, scripts, keyboard

I have this shell script which is supposed to run normally and stop when I press <kbd>q</kbd> button:

```
while true; do
    echo "hello"
    read -t 0.25 -N 1 input
    if [[ $input = "q" ]] || [[ $input = "Q" ]]; then
        break 
    fi
done
```

When I run it, I get this output that keeps being displayed continuously:

```
hello
script.sh: 3: read: Illegal option -t
script.sh: 4: script.sh: [[: not found
script.sh: 4: script.sh: [[: not found
```

But when I press on <kbd>q</kbd> button, it does not stop. It keeps running till I stop it using  <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>c</kbd>.
Any suggestions to fix this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I've just tried on my Ubuntu 16.04 system and it works correctly.

What I've found is, that if you use a generic `sh` instead of `bash`, it won't work
giving out the error

```
read: Illegal option -t
```

Make sure that your script begins with `#!/usr/bin/env bash` or `#!/bin/bash`
and *not* `#!/bin/sh`.

Comment: thank you so much, I remember that it worked for me once, but when I tried it now with a different PC, it didn't.
Thank you.